# List of scientific constants

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

What would be the best way to create a list of constants. Should I make a glossary, or is there better practice or package?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would just use the `tabular` environment.

Comment: If this list is longer than one page, you may need to use a `longtable` environment.

Comment: Do you want the list automatically sorted? Do you want hyperlinks from the notation used in the document to the list?

Comment: Hi Nicola, that would be clean, but might be a bit overkill though :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the simple method using [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable):

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\chapter{System of Units etc}

\section{International system of units}

\begin{longtable}{llll}
\toprule
\bfseries Quantity & \bfseries Unit &
\bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Dimension\\\midrule\endhead
Length & meter & \si{\meter} & \\
Mass & kilogram & \si{\kilo\gram}\\
Frequency & hertz & \si{\hertz} & \si{\per\second}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of table]

Here's the equivalent [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) method:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\glsnoexpandfields
\let\glsunit\glsuseri
\let\glsdim\glsuserii

\newglossaryentry{length}{%
  name=length,%
  description={},%
  symbol={\si{\meter}},
  user1={meter}% unit
}

\newglossaryentry{mass}{%
  name=mass,%
  description={},%
  symbol={\si{\kilo\gram}},
  user1={kilogram}% unit
}

\newglossaryentry{frequency}{%
  name=frequency,%
  description={},%
  symbol={\si{\hertz}},
  user1={hertz},% unit
  user2={\si{\per\second}}% dimension
}

\newglossarystyle{units}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long4col}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\Glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glsentryuseri{##1} &
    \glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glsentryuserii{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule
    \bfseries Quantity &\bfseries Unit&
    \bfseries Symbol& \bfseries Dimension\tabularnewline
    \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
\setglossarystyle{units}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{length}, \glsunit{length}, \glssymbol{length}.

\gls{mass}, \glsunit{mass}, \glssymbol{mass}.

\gls{frequency}, \glsunit{frequency}, \glssymbol{frequency},
\glsdim{frequency}.

\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,title={Systems of Units etc}]

\end{document}
```

The first page:

[image: Image of first page]

The list of symbols:

[image: Image of glossary]

Both methods require two LaTeX runs to ensure the document is up-to-date.