# Generating list of used formulas

Tags: lists, indexing

I'm writing a compilation for a physics course. I want to add a list of all used formulas and a list of all used constants at the end of the document.

The list should contain copies of the aforementioned items and not be a table of contents.

I put my each of my formulas in a table, like this:

```
\begin{document}
            \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \caption*{Mittlere Beschleunigung}
            \label{Mavt}
            \begin{tabular}{llll|
                    >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l |}
                \cline{5-5}
                &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$a:$ Beschleunigung $[\frac{m}{s^2}]$} \\
                &  &  &  & $v:$ Geschwindigkeit $[\frac{m}{s}]$                                               \\
                \multirow{-3}{*}{$a = \frac{v(t_2)-v(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}= \frac{~_\Delta v}{~_\Delta t}$} &  &  &  & $t:$ Zeit $[s]$                                                                    \\ \cline{5-5} 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As we do not know how you input your formulas (especially how you mark the ones which shall be "indexed") it's hard to help you. Please add a minimal compilable example of your input (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173102/table-of-equations-like-list-of-figures
and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203767/list-of-scientific-constants